# Bootstrap accordion show by default on desktop and hide by default mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm kind of new to Bootstrap so I'm not sure how I'd go about this.

I have a simple Bootstrap accordion like in this snippet. It is split into multiple accordions because I want them to be able to expand and collapse independently from each other. (as in can expand and show all items or none, not just one expanded and the others collapsed).

I want to disable the expanding and collapsing on desktop and make sure each item is shown. But then on mobile I only want to have the first item shown and the others collapsed by default.

How can I achieve this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#body1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="body1">
        //heading
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="body1" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="product card-body">
        //content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#body2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="body2">
        //heading
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="body2" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="product card-body">
        //content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
      <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#body3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="body3">
        //heading
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="body3" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="product card-body">
        //content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution for this, please check below

**CSS for desktop**

```
.modified-accordion .card-header{ position: relative;}
.modified-accordion .card-header:after{ content: ''; position: absolute; width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0;}
.modified-accordion .collapse:not(.show){ display: block;}
```

**CSS for Mobile**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.modified-accordion .collapse:not(.show){ display: none;}
.modified-accordion .card-header:after{ display: none;}
}
```

**HTML structure**

```
<div class="accordion modified-accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-body">Contect-1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion modified-accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2</button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="card-body">Content-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion modified-accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"> Collapsible Group Item #3</button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="card-body">Content-3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks perfect thats exactly what I needed

Comment: Of all the solutions for different behavior between mobile and desktop using bootstrap collapse, this is the easiest. No changes to my html, or js, or jquery it only took five lines of css and works great. (I used panel instead of card) with no problems